# Can't retrieve `data` from await + axios in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I am having trouble in retrieving the data from the axios request using await/async. (I'm using ReactJS v. 15.5.4)

Here's the request:

```
handleSearch = async (isbn, upc, item_code) => {
  const { variables } = { isbn, upc, item_code }
  const { data } = await axios.request({
    data: variables,
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/api/v1/products'
  })
  console.log(data)
}
```

It always say

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

But in the `Network` tab in Chrome DevTools, the request has a response code of `200` and I could also see the actual response data

Comment: Is there a `data` object in the response?

Comment: @SatejS none, it the response object is just like a plain `{ ... }`

Comment: Also, is variables printing right?

Comment: yes. no `TypeError` now but still `data` is `undefined`